# why subview id prefixed in the h:message output?

Tags: jsf

Form validation error message contains subviewid:errormsg. I'm able to disactivate form id with prependId="false". how to suppress subviewid in h:message output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the labels yourself by `label` attribute of `<h:inputWhatever>` component.

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.username}" label="Username" />
```

It will then be used instead of client id in validation message.